# Solvability by radicals of an equation of prime degree

Tags: abstract-algebra, galois-theory, solvable-groups

> For which prime $p$ the equation $x^p-p^px+p=0$ is solvable by radicals?

I don't know how to solve this for primes $p\neq 2$, so any help is welcome.

Comment: A short note: It is also clearly solvable for $p=3$. Where did you come across this problem?

Comment: What's a "solvable prime"?

Comment: I edited post, I made a mistake...

Comment: I had this problem on my exam, but I didn't manage to solve it. I can't conclude what is the answer in general case.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Suppose $p > 3$.

Clearly $f(x) = x^p-p^px+p$ is irreducible (over $\Bbb{Q}$) by Eisenstein's criterion.

Now $f'(x) =p x^{p-1} - p^{p} = p (x^{p-1} - p^{p-1})$ has exactly two real roots $\pm p$, and since $f(-p) > 0$ and $f(p) < 0$, it follows that $f$ has exactly $3$ real roots, and $p - 3 > 0$ non-real ones, which come in conjugate pairs.

So the Galois group of $f(x)$ contains a $p$-cycle, which may be taken in the form $$g = (1 2 \dots p),$$ and an element of the form
$$
h = (a_{1} a_{2}) (a_{3} a_{4}) \dots (a_{p-4}, a_{p-3}).
$$

---

**Addendum**

Now, as noted by **@JackSchmidt** in his comment below, a result of Galois applies. This states that if $p$ is an odd prime, and $G$ is a transitive subgroup of $S_{p}$, then the following are equivalent:

1. $G$ has a unique $p$-Sylow subgroup, which is then normal in $G$;
2. $G$ is soluble;
3. $G$ is (similar to) a subgroup of the affine group on the line over the field with $p$ elements;
4. $G$ is a Frobenius group, that is, the only element of $G$ fixing two distinct points is the identity.

Here I am quoting from B. Huppert's Endliche Gruppen I, Satz II.3.6.

Of interest to us is the fact that if $G$ is as in (1), or (4), then, as noted by **@JackSchmidt**, the involution $h$ must normalize $\langle g \rangle$. But involutions doing this are
$$
(2, p) (3, p-1) \dots \left(\dfrac{p+1}{2}, \dfrac{p+3}{2}\right),
$$
and its conjugates under powers of $g$. These involutions invert $g$, as $g^{-1} = (1, p, p-1, \dots, 3, 2)$.

Thus an involution normalizing $\langle g \rangle$ is a product of $(p-1)/2$ disjoint transpositions, unlike $h$, which is a product of $(p-3)/2$ disjoint transpositions. Therefore (1) is not satisfied, hence (2) is not satisfied, and $G$ is not soluble.

Comment: How did you conclude that it contains a $p$-cycle?

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft, as $f$ is irreducible, the degree over the rationals of the splitting field is divisible by $p$, and then so is the order of the Galois group, which thus contains an element of order $p$. Now the Galois group is a subgroup of $S_{p}$, and the elements of order $p$ in $S_{p}$ are the $p$-cycles.

Comment: Ahh, of course. It does seem like overkill to use that theorem, but I don't recall a sufficient result off the top of my head (one can probably make good use of the fact that it is a primitive permutation group in some way).

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft, I know it's overkill, I am looking for a simpler result to be applied.

Comment: @Andreas Caranti Could you, please, provide more details - why this group has to be $S_p$ or $A_p$? Thanks in advance.

Comment: @alans, just done.

Comment: In my exam (where I had to solve this problem), I couldn't use O'Nan-Scott (since I'm not familiar with theorems listed), but only "elementary", well-known things... Is there any other way to conclude Galois group?

Comment: @alans, there is definitely, but I cannot recall it at the moment. Perhaps you can name some results you should have covered about generating sets of $S_{p}$ or  $A_{p}$.

Comment: As I recall, in all problems in class we used one transposition and p-cycle as generating set, but this doesn't help in this case.

Comment: @alans, yes, that one is the standard way to construct an example of an equation of degree $5$ which is insoluble by radicals. This only helps here for $p = 5$, of course.

Comment: I think Galois proved that a solvable permutation group of degree p normalized its Sylow p-subgroup. At any rate, any minimal normal subgroup is complemented by a one point stabilizer, so that minimal normal subgroup has order p, and is a Sylow p-subgroup by comparison to Sym(p).

Comment: @JackSchmidt, great quote, thanks a bunch. For some reason, that's a result I keep forgetting. Will edit answer accordingly.